# When does flink initiates RocksDBKeyedStateBackend directory delete?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

My Flink jobs runs for few days without any issues, but after somedays it kills the tm and restarts the entire job.
in the log I found this,
org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackend  - Deleting existing instance base directory /tmp/flink-io-4b455efa-bcde-4ef2-aed3-c66ca9d8933e/job_152b986e7e5a6f411780849f13ce4bc8_op_KeyedProcessOperator_a1c286a47e97622aa92a8f6cd4115854__1_4__uuid_4b53ff24-e240-48d6-b438-3ab2d05cbdb8

after it deleted the statestore file, it throws this error, because i am fetching data from statestore there.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at c.c.w.d.s.b.aggregator.StateProcessFunction.addEvent(StateProcessFunction.java:81)
    at c.cs.w.d.s.b.a.StateProcessFunction.processElement(StateProcessFunction.java:113)
    at c.c.w.d.s.b.a.StateProcessFunction.processElement(ContactStateProcessFunction.java:26)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.KeyedProcessOperator.processElement(KeyedProcessOperator.java:85)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processElement(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:164)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:143)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:279)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.run(StreamTask.java:301)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:406)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:705)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:530)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

question is when and why flink backend statestore file delete initiated ? is there something which is not printed in the log ?

Comment: Optimized code formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of concurrency. mapstate.get() throws an exception, sometimes when rocksdbbackend asynch thread deleting the expired data it locks the file, at the same time if you try get it throws exception which is causing tm to restart.

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of Flink that message has been reworded to be clearer:

> Closed RocksDB State Backend. Cleaning up RocksDB working directory {}.

This is happening in `RocksDBKeyedStateBackend.dispose()`, which is called when Flink is shutting down. Flink only depends on RocksDB for transient state. After restarting from a failure, new RocksDB instances are created from the most recent checkpoint. (Though if you using local recovery, the story is a bit more complex.)

What version of Flink are you using? Incremental, or full checkpoints? Local recovery? Perhaps you are experiencing a bug which has since been fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @David Anderson, I am trying to understand why does flink shutdown, I was thinking flink is crashing because of this. 
I am using Incremental checkpoint and yes local recovery.
i am creating backend like this:
StateTtlConfig.newBuilder(Time.hours(2))
            .setUpdateType(UpdateType.OnCreateAndWrite)
            .setStateVisibility(StateVisibility.NeverReturnExpired)
            .cleanupInRocksdbCompactFilter(5000)
            .build();
do you see any problem with this ?